# If I choose to try Ubuntu can I save anything I download?

Tags: files, live-cd

I have recently Installed Ubuntu to a usb as a portable OS, however I was wondering what would happen when I choose to install something on Ubuntu without actually installing Ubuntu on my pc, Would the Installed file save upon shutting down my pc? or would it be removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two cases we have then

- If you have save the file in the home directory or any of live mounted partition then it will be lost after restart.
- If you have saved else where in any other partition then it will be saved as usually & even you did a restart its cost nothing to your data.

hope that helps,:)

Comment: Thank you for the rapid reply, Exactly what I was looking for :)